# Drain connection in knex takes more time than expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, knex.js

I'm having mocha tests with project that uses knex pool.

The issue I have is when test ends, it keep waiting until knex pool is drained, and it takes extra seconds (about 5-10) to finish mocha run.

Code example:

knex initialized:

```
const Knex = require('knex');
const knex = new Knex({
  client: 'pg',
  pool: { min: 1, max: 10 },
  connection: {},
  searchPath: 'knex,public',
  // debug: true,
});
```

Mocha test drains connection:

```
  after((done) => {
    knex.destroy().then(done);
  })
```

What I would like to accomplish is any of both:

1. drain knex connections faster
2. somehow mocha finish test without waiting knex draining

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality changed while ago in mocha

> ## 2879: By default, Mocha will no longer force the process to exit once all tests complete. This means any test code (or code under test)
>
> which would normally prevent node from exiting will do so when run in
> Mocha. Supply the --exit flag to revert to pre-v4.0.0 behavior
> (@ScottFreeCode, @boneskull)

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

If the above doesn't help you can always call process.exit(0) in done to force killing the process with success exit code.

AFAIK in knex side there is no force options for force killing the connections.

Answer (score 0):

This will help your connection from draining.

```
const config = {
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      host: hostname,
      user: username,
      password: password,
      database: datbase
    },
    pool: {
      min: 0,
      max: 10
    },
    acquireConnectionTimeout: 1000
  }
  var Knex = require('knex')

  this.functioname = () => {
    var output = {}
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      var knex = new Knex(config)
      knex(tablename)
        .select()
        .then((result) => {
          if (result.length > 0) {
            output.error = false
            output.result = result
          } else {
            output.error = true
          }
          resolve(output)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          err.error = true
          resolve(err)
        })
        .finally(() => {
          knex.destroy()
        })
    })
  }
```